# How to run script in new terminal window and close 30 seconds later

Tags: linux, terminal, termite

I have wrote a script, and i am running xmonad and default terminal termite;just saying if it is important :), maybe there is a solution in xmonad.

```
, ((altMask, xK_x),
     spawn "termite --hold -e /home/emre/pipix.sh")
```

when i type in terminal

```
timeout 30 script.sh
```

it seems working. However when i type

```
termite --hold -e timeout 5 pipi.sh
```

I got this warning message

```
Try 'timeout --help' for more information.
```

What am i doing wrong or how can i make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Often, if there are spaces in a command being passed as a single option on CLI, we often need to encase the command in quotation marks so that the program knows that the `timeout 5 pipi.sh` is a single command and not three separate input options.

```
termite --hold -e "timeout 5 pipi.sh"
```

Mind you, this is my guess based on common issues passing a line of code to a program on command line.

Comment: After 5 seconds i got this warning (termite:4105): GLib-WARNING **: 11:55:27.131: GChildWatchSource: Exit status of a child process was requested but ECHILD was received by waitpid(). See the documentation of g_child_watch_source_new() for possible causes.

Answer (score 0):

i came across this post and i wanted to post it here.

https://www.tecmint.com/run-linux-command-with-time-limit-and-timeout/

Whoever needs to put a timelimit to command need to install the "timelimit" and use before their command

mine follows in xmonad.hs as this;

```
  , ((altMask, xK_c),
     spawn "timelimit -t25 termite --hold -e /home/emre/pipi.sh")
```

Answer (score -2):

The following WAS tested and works as expected..

```
#!/bin/sh
temp=$$

(sleep 30; kill $temp; exit) &

echo "Hello. Testing timeout with ed."
# Your never ending code goes here instead. 
# Because ed is a new process you will have to kill it.
# killall ed would be replaced with the program name. killall XXX
(sleep 30; killall ed; exit) &

# run ed and put it in append mode and add a few characters.
# ed is never given the . and q! commands so it waits. 
ed

a

1234

echo "Should not get here"
# Should get a Terminated message and script exits in 30 seconds.
# And the process for  ed  is killed is in 30 seconds..
```

Ken

Comment: How does this answer the question? Also using `exit` in a subshell would just exit the subshell, which is what would happen anyway when the code within it is done.

Comment: xterm -hold -e  script.sh
and it says kill: (3691) -  no process \n kill: (3670) -  no process... "no process" would be different i am translating

Comment: (termite:3804): GLib-WARNING **: 12:25:33.365: GChildWatchSource: Exit status of a child process was requested but ECHILD was received by waitpid(). See the documentation of g_child_watch_source_new() for possible causes.